# How do I turn this data from an SQL database table into a dict?

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

The SQL table is simple, 3 columns.

```
id | guild | word
```

`id` is just your usual db counter that I'm not interested in, the others are strings.

Multiple `word`s belong to one `guild`, e.g.

```
1 |  5597  |  egg
2 |  5597  |  cheese
3 |  5534  |  flour
4 |  5534  |  milk
```

I'd like to take the result of `SELECT * FROM table` and turn it into a dictionary, structured such that the `guild` is used as keys, the corresponding dictionary value is a list of all the `word`s with common `guild`s. Two different guilds could share a common `word`, or might not, this is not significant.

In this dict structure, you'd access the word "cheese" from line 2 above as `my_dict["5597"][1]`.
(I don't intend to work with the list data explicitly like this in practice, just doing this for for example sake.)

Hopefully that made sense.

I've obtained `rows` (tuples) of the SQL data using sqlite3 as such:

```py
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect("file.db")
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute("SELECT guild,word FROM table")
>>> rows = c.fetchall()
>>> print(rows[0])
(5597, egg)
```

What's an efficient way to go about building the dict of `word` lists from here? Not against using non-standard libs if needed. The use is such that I can access a guild's list of words from knowing only the guild's name.

Comment: You could use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) `d=defaultdict(list); for r in c: d[r[0]].append(r[1])`

Comment: @Pynchia Thanks, if you leave this as an answer I'll accept, it worked beautifully :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)
and iterate on the cursor directly

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for row in c:
    d[row[0]].append(row[1])
```

To make it more readable change the loop to

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for guild, word in c:
    d[guild].append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d = {}
for row in rows:
    key, value = row
    try:
        d[key].append(value)
    except KeyError:
        d[key] = [value]
```

This works as follows. For each `guild` if it's not in the dictonary we add it and set value to a list with one element (`word`). If `guild` is already in the dictonary we simply append ned `word` to it's value list.

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel. Use the python's standard library: see my comment to the question